# replace special character in boost regex replace c++

Tags: c++, regex, unicode

I'm trying to replace a special character Æ with space using the boost regex replace, but I cannot do so. In order to replace the special character, can anyone please help me with what exactly my regular expression should be. Below is the code snippet which I am trying out.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    regex escape("\\xC6");
    const char* specialChar = "bananaÆ,test";
    string xml = regex_replace(specialChar, escape, "");

    cout << specialChar << "\n";
    cout << xml << '\n';
 }
```

**Output:**

```
bananaÆ,test

bananaÆ,test
```

Comment: You are using an `std::regex`, not boost.

Comment: On my machine, I changed the one line to `regex escape("\\xC3\\x86");` and then it worked.

Comment: In which encoding is your file (utf-8?)? `\xC6` is extended ascii...

Comment: @Eljay: or `regex escape("\u00C6");` [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/c6b9vEGcK)

Comment: is there any way we can do the same using boost regex?
@Jarod42

Comment: Sorry Ziya, I'm not sure.  I use Boost all the time, but I've not used Boost regex.

Comment: You might look at [boost_regex/unicode](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/unicode.html) to really handle unicode. Else you might consider string as normal char-sequence (as we do with `\xC3\x86` or `\u00C6`) and look for the appropriate utf-8 sequence(s).